# Array to UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

This sounds like it's easy and from the tutorials it looks very easy.

I have followed the tutorials from their words EXACTLY and still can not get the array to display on my UITableView.

Here is my code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
   salesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

  //Add items
  [salesArray  addObject:@"Credit"];
  [salesArray  addObject:@"Debit"];
  [salesArray  addObject:@"EBT"];


  //Set the title
  self.navigationItem.title = @"Sale Type's";
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
                      numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{return [salesArray count];}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
        cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  if(cell == nil)
  {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero 
    reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];
  }
  NSString *value = [salesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  cell.textLabel.text = value;
  return cell;
}
```

And yes, I have declared it in the .h file and the .m file.
Any help in any directions would be great, thank you!

Comment: So i have tried the two things they mentioned below, and it still is not showing me my String Array as the list of titles on the UITableView?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Declare your `salesArray` as your property and in the the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, use

```
cell.textLabel.text = [self.salesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: Thank you, this was great help from both of you.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that your view controller extends UITableViewController? If so, you just need to add this line at the end of your viewDidLoad and/or viewDidAppear methods:

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Also, I would use self.salesArray instead of salesArray. Not exactly sure what the difference is, but I have had issues in the past not prepending "self" to some of my variables.

Comment: Thank you, this was great help from both of you!

Comment: @armohan: Normal variables when declared inside the class will affect only the block in which it was declared in. If you declare an object as a property of that class, you can still call the object with the keyword `self.object` and this would help you refer to the object at various blocks of the code, and in other classes as well...

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be ok but I think you forgot to change the number of sections from zero to one.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my point of view it's much better and easily to understand according to the code below:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
class testTableViewController: UITableViewController {    
override func viewDidLoad{
super.viewDidLoad()
}

let nameList = ["name1","name2","name3","name4","name5","name6"]

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int)->
Int{
return nameList.count
}

override func tableView(TableView:UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("test_row", forIndexPath: indexPath)
let row1 = nameList[indexPath.row]

cell.textLabel? .text = row1
return cell
}

}
```

Comment: Objective-C not Swift. This was also in 2011, thanks for showing everyone the alternative if they were using swift though.